# MySQL Memory Tables - Master dealing with restart

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

We're in the process of considering using MySQL Memory tables to help with some temporary tasks (think of a queue).  It will be replicated to a slave that will likely be a MyIsam table. Upon restart of the master, the Memory table will be cleared. According to the docs,

> when a MEMORY table is used on a master for the first time since it
>   was started, a DELETE statement is written to the master's binary log
>   automatically, thus synchronizing the slave to the master again.

the Slave table will be cleared after the Memory table is cleared I would like, if possible, for the Memory table data to be recreated from the slave.

In the same section in the doc it says:

> if you use the --init-file option to populate the MEMORY table on the
>   master at startup, it ensures that this time interval is zero.

I believe this is saying that what we're trying to do is possible, however I'm not finding much in the way of docs to support this. Is it possible to recreate a Master table from a Slave upon restart?